# What could be causing 'AMQPLinkError' when completing messages in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azureservicebus

Azure Service Bus exception when completing messages:
ServiceBusError: The required field 'first' is not set in 'amqp:disposition:list'. Error condition: amqp:invalid-field.

So essentially what im trying to do is read a batch of messages from the servicebus, iterate over the messages to collect the payloads, combine them, and write it all to storage and go back to iterate over the batch of messages again to complete them one by one.

The code works fine in terms of getting the payloads into storage, however once the messages are being completed off, i get this error that i cannot find much information about and it's not very clear on what the missing piece is meant to be or why it's not there... But the underlying exceptions is "AMQPLinkError"

[Code block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2UBh.png)

The code is pretty much similar to what's in the documentation with some small changes.

I've so far tried both sync and async version, tried playing around with batch sizes and timing params, but still get the same issue.

The weirdest thing is that some runs complete fine, however at other times this exception is raised without clear reasoning as to why.

All this code runs in databricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @Andrius Vitkauskas,

I work on that team and we are fixing that bug right now. To go around there are two ways to do so:

1. use the uamqp transport by passing in `uamqp_transport=True` during connection. You will have to pip install uamqp
2. go back to the previous version of service bus, which essentially moves you back to uamqp.

Sorry about the issues. We hope to get this resolved asap.

Comment: Brilliant, seems to work perfectly using that uamqp_transport. Also to mention if this helps your team that without that uamqp_transport, the servicebus was ingesting all messages requested, but that even when the the jobs succeed correctly, not all messages would be completed. So from my testing it looked like from 500 messages ingested, only around 50ish would disappear from the servicebus, others would increment the delivery count. That's not the case with that uamqp_transport arg, all 500 seem to be consumed and dropped from servicebus as it should.

Comment: Thank you for that feedback @AndriusVitkauskas. We have it narrowed down to a problem while completing large messages, would you happen to know the size of the messages that are having trouble getting completed ?

Comment: @AndriusVitkauskas we have just released an update, version 7.11.0 that fixes this issue. If you are able to try it that would be great, as it would mean not requiring uamqp to be installed.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but the code is running fine in async and without the uamqp_transport now. Im not sure if this is related since you mentioned the large messages, but I'm still seeing some messages getting dead lettered after 10 attempts despite not having any errors in the code and the code blocks completing in 12ish seconds for 500 messages. Even seen around 300 messages struggling to complete during every run and just increment the delivery count, reducing the batch size to 200 cleared the sub in a few runs. Not sure if it's a coincidence or something related?

Comment: @AndriusVitkauskas sorry that you are having issues. If youd like you can open up an issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues and someone from my team can assist you. If you can provide some repro code for the issue and some debug logs by following the steps here

```python
import logging, sys

logger = logging.getLogger('azure.servicebus')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))
client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(logging_enable=True)
```